# Calling delete() causes server error

Tags: php, silverstripe

Why is my `delete()` causing server error in Silverstripe? Below is the code:

```
$product = Product::create();
$product = Product::get()->filter(array('Price' => 26.32));
$product->delete();
```

The above is in `requireDefaultRecords()` and run when /dev/build?flush

Comment: the error is "server error" but when delete() is commented out there is no error.

Comment: Your error reporting settings are wrong, that's why you don't get specific errors.

Comment: @markus what do you recommend I put for error settings?

Comment: You need to show every possible error in development: http://www.phptherightway.com/#error_reporting

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Product::get()->filter(array('Price' => 26.32))` will return a `DataList`, not a `Product` object. This is because `Product::get()->filter()` could find more than one product. This will still return a `DataList` even if the `filter` function only finds one item.

What you need to do is go through each item in the `DataList` and delete each one.

```
$newProduct = Product::create();
$products = Product::get()->filter(array('Price' => 26.32));

foreach ($products as $product) {
    $product->delete(); 
}
```

Comment: This solves it, thanks 3dgoo, just wondering why there is no need for save() when deleting but saving needs a save?

Comment: `$products->removeAll()` will also work. It calls `remove()`, which calls `removeByID($id)` and `delete()` for each item in the list

Comment: `write()` needs to be called to write all changes to the database. `delete()` doesn't need need  a `write()` call as it's not making any changes to the object, it simply deletes the object.

Comment: @elliot_at_silverstripe, it is unfortunate that the API is called `removeAll` and not `deleteAll` as while there is `filter`, the name implies that it is just removing from the list, not deleting from the DB. This becomes a problem when you turn a `DataList` into an `ArrayList` or even if you are going over a `HasManyList`, the meaning of `remove` changes.